# Uncheck the checkbox when clicked On Button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have checkbox list and  I want to clear all checked data  after Clear button.
The data is fetch from json for checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in array" >
    <label class="Form-label--tick">
        <input type="checkbox" id="statusid"  value="{{data.id}}" class="Form-label-checkbox" ng-click="print(data.id)">
        <span class="Form-label-text" id="statusname" value="{{data.name}}"> {{data.name}}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
  $scope.clearFilters = function() {
     document.getElementById('statusid').value="";
     document.getElementById('statusname').value="";
  };
```

`clearFilters()` is called when Clear Button is clicked.But I am not able clear the checked boxes.It remains checked even after the clear button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not angular. Don't try to modify any DOM elements directly, but use the $scope variables to change their value.

In angular the checkbox return true or false so to uncheck a checkbox just change it's value to false.

so your code should look like this:

```
  $scope.clearFilters = function() {
     $scope.data.id = false;
     $scope.data.name = ""; 
  };
```